# 2^(x-1) + 2^(x-2) + 2^(x-3) < 2^x

Tags: induction

Consider the recurrence:
tn ={ \begin{array}{ll}
1 & n = 1 \\
1 & n = 2 \\
1 & n = 3 \\
t_{n-1} + t_{n-2} + t_{n-3} &  n \geq 4
\end{array}
For all natural numbers $n$, starting at $1$, $t_n < 2^n$

Comment: It is not very difficult to prove this claim. What have you tried so far?

Comment: $2^{x-1}+2^{x-2}+2^{x-3} = 4(2^{x-3})+2(2^{x-3})+2^{x-3} = 7(2^{x-3})=\frac{7}{8}(2^x)<2^x$

Comment: I started with induction, and did the base cases etc. What I am stuck on is i got to the point where tn = tn-1 + tn-2 + tn-3 so that implies that tn < 2^n-1 +2^n-2 + 2^n-3 but how do i prove that those three combined are less than 2^n?

Comment: What's the connection between the title and the body ?

Comment: how do u know to do that? I dont understand what you did exactly, could you clairify it for me?

Comment: Okay, I'm considering it.  What am I supposed to consider about it?

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in title,
$2^{x-1} + 2^{x-2} + 2^{x-3} < 2^x$ is what we need to prove.

$$LHS = 2^{x-1} + 2^{x-2} + 2^{x-3}$$

Taking $2^{x-3}$ common,

$$LHS = 2^{x-3}(2^2+2+1)=7\times2^{x-3}$$

$$RHS = 2^x=8\times2^{x-3}$$
Clearly $LHS < RHS$.

Comment: But the question in the title is entirely different than the question in the body.  Which is the one you want to do?

Comment: @fleablood OP wanted to prove that $t_n < 2^n$ using induction. His way of expressing the question was not clear.