# A Proof by Strong Induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I am having trouble approaching this question.

""''

t is defined as follows:

[image: Definition of t]

""''

I want to prove that last statement in the image.

I have been thinking about proving by strong induction. However, I am also confused about how many (minimum amount of) base cases do I need to take. Any suggestions and guidance is appreciated.

Note: If you think there is a simpler way to prove this without using strong induction, then kindly shed light on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506331/2x-1-2x-2-2x-3-2x#comment5176373_2506331

Comment: Strong induction is a natural approach, and works very easily.

Comment: Strong induction in this case can simply be rephrased as straightforward induction by letting the statement be $P(k)$ is true iff each of the following three inequalities are true: $t_k<2^k,t_{k-1}<2^{k-1},t_{k-2}<2^{k-2}$.  There is little reason to make the change however, as wording the proof using strong induction should not cause any additional difficulty or discomfort.

Comment: [Another duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506772/mathematical-strong-induction-proof-involving-recurrence#comment5177369_2506772) (*albeit one that has not received a full answer, but plenty of guidance in the comments*).

Comment: The fact that the question is an _exact_ duplicate (i.e., the image is the same) suggests two students from the same class.

Comment: @quasi The fact that you conclude this suggets that you are really smart. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base case: $t_1 = 1 < 2^1 = 2$, $t_2 = 1 < 2^2 = 4$, $t_3 = 1 < 2^3 = 8$.

Assume there is some $k\geq 3$ such that $t_i < 2^i$ for all $ i \leq k$.

$t_k < 2^k$, $t_{k-1} < 2^{k-1}$, and $t_{k-2} < 2^{k-2}$. Then from here show that somehow $t_{k+1} < 2^{k+1}$.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you say  " k≥3 "  instead of just  " k>3 ", since we already have shown the third base case to be true? 
And also why  " i ≤ k " ? Should it not be just i<k ? I am so confused as to what my Inductive Hypothesis should be..... please help. I'm going crazy

Comment: @AI_Bush Well the way that induction works is that you are assuming that for at least one $k$, your proposition holds. If you say $k>3$, then you can't say that. That's what the base case is for, it's to show that the proposition holds at least once, and the induction later builds off of that.

Comment: @AI_Bush Now strong induction you're assuming that for at least one $k$ we have that the proposition holds for all $i \leq k$.